If I was sexually assaulted but didn't tell anyone, how do I go about writing this in my book?
I'm writing a book based on stuff that happened. I've changed names but want to keep the characters authentic to my life.  I was assaulted but never reported it. I want to write about it, but I don't want the guy to sue me, despite the fact I'm not using anyone's real name. He doesn't believe it was assault but if I publish and he sues, he risks exposing a crime he committed several times. How do I go about writing this into a book?

First of all, I'm very sorry to hear that you went through such a thing.
If you intend to change the names - as in, not using your name and your attacker's name - then I don't see what grounds he could possibly have to sue. You're not accusing him of anything. It's possible that there are certain distinctive details that may cause him to realise that you based the character off of him, but as you said, I don't see how he can sue you over that without admitting his involvement and exposing himself to potential legal action.
I would be very careful about how much detail you go into when describing the assault, partly to reduce whatever risk there may be of your attacker recognising his own description, but primarily to reduce the risk of triggering PTSD flashbacks in any readers who may have gone through the same experience. Sexual assault in fiction is a thorny issue, and I know that some people (both survivors and others) object to detailed depictions of it - see the answers to this question, for example.
If you're determined to describe your experience in detail, I would recommend putting some kind of trigger warning, either on the blurb or in a foreword, so that readers know what they're getting themselves into, and aren't shocked when they turn the page to find a sexual assault scene they weren't expecting (and might have turned them away from reading the book had they known it was there).
Lastly, if you're posting under your real name, I would suggest changing your username, just in case.

If you publish this book under your real name and you describe circumstances of your real life it is highly likely that everyone who knows you well enough and reads the book will understand that the book is autobiograpical (to some extent) and that the protagonist is based on you.
Your only chances that the contents of the narrative aren't attributed to you is to publish this book under a pen name (but there is the risk that your real identity is eventually uncovered) or to change everything so much that it bears absolutely no resemblance to your real life (and even then some people will assume that you have put something of yourself into it, the more so, the more it feels authentic).
You know how some people always assume that those who are very vocal about a certain topic are somehow involved in it, either as victim or as perpetrator? That is what is going to happen. And it will start rumors.
If you want no one ever to know (or guess) that this happened to you, don't write about it.

I'll admit firstly, that I'm not experienced in working with or talking very much about such experiences. I'm sorry that you went through it. These are ideas and considerations that may suit some stories/situations and not others, so take from it what you can.
Fiction and your question(s)
It seems to me that many stories involve or revolve around experiences that the author has either had personally or close to them in their life - The typical 'write what you know' comes from something like this. It varies, though, how we write these experiences and insights into a story, and there is an immense freedom in writing that can be both an advantage and a disadvantage depending on what our goals are with our writing. Still, as others have pointed out, it may be very clear from the final story, that it is based on real events. Additionally, certain people may know who the involved parties are.
Your story
'The same' situation or life experience can be written into almost any story within any genre but feel and be portrayed vastly differently. To (finally) address your question directly, your concerns may be more or less relevant depending on how true to your life they are written, and so you can choose to write it into a story that in no other ways resemble your lived life - Like a fantasy or otherwise strongly fictional setting, or using a different type of assault but 'the same way of living with/through it', or switching the 'genders' of the involved parties and so on. These may severely vary in how satisfyingly they end up portraying your experiences.
I understand that these considerations may not apply to your specific story, but it might make sense for other people.
Your work(s)
Alternatively, consider what you're writing 'your first take on it.' Even if you've written down thoughts, this seems to be your first take on writing it into a story.
Perhaps, writing this book is, initially or finally, just for you, for your process of working with what happened. It may be the first or ground-laying work for other works of yours to come that deal with injustice, power-relations and structures, gender roles, dealing with feelings and secrets, or a multitude of other experiences and problems.

I am in no way attempting to talk you out of writing this story. If anything,  if I may be so bold, I think the story should be told and heard - consequences be what they may. But your concerns are valid, and your safety and well-being is of the utmost importance. I hope you find a suitable solution to your situation.
